# Why did changing the language of my project cause the error “Missing required parameters for [Route: cars.show] [URI: {language}/cars/{car}]”?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to change the language of my website.

I have an error that I have a missing parameter while I think my parameters are fine.
Missing required parameters for [***Route***: cars.show] [***URI***: {language}/cars/{car}].
language and id of car ...

***web.php file***

```php
Route::redirect('/','/en');
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'], function () {

Route::resource('/cars','CarController');
});
```

***blade file***

```html
<a href="{{ route('cars.show',app()->getLocale(),$car->id) }}" class="show">more details</a>
```

Comment: O don't think giving a parameter to prefix is possible, are your sure about that part?

Answer (score 0):

You type it wrong.

```
<a href="{{ route('cars.show',app()->getLocale(),$car->id) }}"> Your Link</a>
```

This will Fix it

```
<a href="{{ route('cars.show',['language' => app()->getLocale(), 'car' => $car->id]) }}"> Your Link </a>
```

[Laravel Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes)